# How to implement puppet proxys for nodes on different network location

Tags: linux-networking, puppet, puppetmaster, provisioning, puppet-agent

we are using puppet but we have some problems with different nodes on different networks, I would like to know if we can use some kind of proxys/satellites in order to connect the nodes from different networks to a centralized puppet master , which I asume is unavoidable .

We cannot use iptables because os security requirements .

We also cannot expose the main puppet master to every new network, so we need to use some kind of proxy for every new network

Comment: We don't do product recommendations, but Red Hat Satellite Server or the upstream project Foreman w/ Katello does exactly what you are describing.

Comment: Redhat satellite is just a tool for channels aubscription, has no relation with the question. Will take a look to foreman